# Best place to put constant memory which is known before kernel launch and never changed

Tags: c, cuda

I have an array of integers which size is known before the kernel launch but not during the compilation stage. The upper bound on the size is around 10000 float3 elements (I guess that means 10000 * 3 * 4 = ~120KB). It is not known at the compile time.

All threads scan linearly through (at most) all of the elements in the array.

Comment: You dont have so much constant memory on the GPU for your example.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the size at runtime, then if it will fit use `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`, or otherwise use texture or global memory.  This is slightly messy, you will have to have some parameter to tell the kernel where the data is.  As always, always test actual performance.  Different access patterns can have drastically different speeds in different types of memory.

Another thought is to take a step back and look at the algorithm again.  There are often ways of dividing the problem differently to get the constant table to always fit into constant memory.

Answer (score 0):

If all threads in a warp access the same elements at the same time then you should probably consider using constant memory, since this is not only cached, but it also has a broadcast capability whereby all threads can read the same address in a single cycle.

Comment: That would be ideal, yes, but apparently constant memory size needs to be known at the compile time. I'm pretty sure I've seen a couple of posts saying that on SO and on nvidia-forums.

If I'm wrong (and that would be very good!), could you sketch a brief example demonstrating that, preferably with cudaMemcpyToSymbol? I've tried quite a few variations, neither of which worked.

Comment: Sorry - I missed that part of the question - presumably though if you have a sensible upper limit on the maximum size of this constant data then you could just hard code this upper limit at compile time and then just use as much of it as you actually need at run-time ?

Comment: Apparently constant memory is capped at 64K =( 
And no, I have an algorithm where bigger-is-better - the bigger my array can be, the better it is.

Comment: Ah - sorry - in that case I think you might want to consider texture memory, which has a lot of the same attributes as constant memory but with fewer limitations.

Comment: Although texture memory will be cached, I think the access to the same location is not broadcast.

Comment: @pQB: I think you're right - for CUDA 1.x devices texture memory is probably still a win over global memory, but for CUDA 2.x devices with caches on device memory it may just be better to use global memory.

Comment: @Paul neigbors prefectch on texture memory is still a plus in 2D.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the free constant memory after compile your kernels and allocate it statically.

```
__constant__ int c[ALL_I_CAN_ALLOCATE];
```

Then, copy your data to constant memory using cudaMemcpyToSymbol().

I think this might answer your question but your requirement for constant memory exceed the limits of the GPU.

I'll recommend other approaches, i.e. use the share memory which can broadcast data if *all* threads in a halfwarp read from the same location.